# Is there a better way to List Queues in an Azure Storage Account in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-queues, azure-storage-account

I'm stuck trying to get all the queues in an Azure Storage Account in C#. I've been trying to use the API endpoint shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-queues1

But it seems to be extremely old. It doesn't support bearer tokens and instead requires a SharedKey, the code I found to generate a SharedKey is also very old and can be found here (in the sample application):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth

Before I commit to this course of action, I wanted to ask if anyone knows any better/more up to date way to get a list of all the queues in a given Azure Storage Account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Storage Queues client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Storage.Queues_12.11.0/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Queues/README.md) to perform management operations like these.

The `QueueServiceClient` class has a method `GetQueues` that will list all queues in an account, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueserviceclient.getqueuesasync?view=azure-dotnet)